# boot-repair Does not add Widnows 7 to the grub menu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, debian, boot-repair

I have a laptop with *Debian 7*, *Windows 7* and *Ubuntu 13.04*. I have decided to upgrade to *Ubuntu 13.10*, and installed the *Ubuntu* partition afresh.

After the re-installation, *Windows 7* disappeared from the grub menu. I booted the machine with a live cd and started [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Boot-repair [seemed to have identified the installed OS's well](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6815621/), including the *Windows* partition:

```
...
sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sda5 and looks at sector 817082808 of the same hard 
                       drive for core.img, but core.img can not be found at 
                       this location.
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 13.10 
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img
...
```

And the installation went well without errors:

```
grub-install (GRUB) 2.00-19ubuntu2.1,grub-install (GRUB) 2.

Reinstall the GRUB of sda5 into the MBR of sda
Installation finished. No error reported.
grub-install /dev/sda: exit code of grub-install /dev/sda:0

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda5 update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-15-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
Found Debian GNU/Linux (7.0) on /dev/sda6
Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
```

The full report is available [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6815621/).

Still, after reboot I only see the *Ubuntu* and *Debian* records in grub, without the *Windows 7* section:

[image]

Any idea what's wrong with the boot-repair fix attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough, [`update-grub`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281119/how-do-you-run-update-grub) did the trick:

```
$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-15-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda2
Found Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda4
Found Debian GNU/Linux (7.0) on /dev/sda6
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [*SuperGRUB2*](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/super-grub2-disk-stable/) Disk for your issue.