# Ubuntu and Windows 7 dual-boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7, hard-drive

I have two HDDs, 80Gb each. On the first HDD, I have windows 7, on the second HDD, I've installed Ubuntu, but I don't understand why can't I use Ubuntu.

When I restart my PC, it doesn't ask me about Windows 7 or Ubuntu, Windows 7 simply starts.

**Note:** When I've intalled Ubuntu I picked the second option "Erase disk and install Ubuntu", because the first option did't let me install Ubuntu on the second HDD, only on the first one.

Comment: See the part 8-11 of my answer to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/533732/install-windows-alongside-ubuntu-14-04-on-second-hard-drive/533808#533808

Answer (score 0):

You may have correctly installed Ubuntu on the second HDD, but most likely your BIOS is set to use the first HDD as the boot device. That's why you do not see the GRUB screen at all.

You just simply need to change the boot order in the BIOS. Or if it is easier, you can swap the order of the disks, by swapping the SATA connectors on the motherboard.

Comment: Swapping connections most likely will not change anything. But regarding boot order it is correct.

Comment: If i change the boot order in BIOS , then GRUB screen is going to work?, or it will boot only ubuntu

Comment: It will get you to the GRUB screen, where you can select what you want

Comment: @EmanuelLucaci: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**