# ubuntu 16/18 with nvidia. boot hangs. nomodeset, nouveau.modeset, recovery mode - nothing helps

Tags: boot, 16.04, 18.04, grub2, nvidia

After successful installation of the Ubuntu 16.04 on a new Asus laptop(with Nvidia GeForce graphic card) I was asked to install software updates. The update went successfully and it asked to reboot the system.

Now I can not boot to the system. There so many content about this issue online, but it all relies on the terminal and I can't access it. In fact, this is my biggest problem.

The GRUB menu is there, I can modify the boot command, add `nomodeset`, remove `quiet splash`, add `nouveau.modeset=0` or `nvidia.modeset=0` - but nothing of this helps. I still see the frozen dark purple screen as soon as I hit `Ctrl+X`. Recovery mode doesn't help either. Tried with all these params as well. The only difference recovery mode makes - I will see these two lines before it hangs:

```
Loading Linux 4.15.0-58-generic ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...
```

I tried installing Ubuntu 18 first, run into the same issue. Thought falling back to 16 may help.

**UPDATE:** managed to log in by adding `dis_ucode_ldr` option. But have no idea what to do next.

Comment: If this command works for you than you will want to make it permanent in grub. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/281119/how-do-you-run-update-grub

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by upgrading to Ubuntu 18 and then **downgrading the intel-microcode package** to the previous version using [this instruction](https://askubuntu.com/a/1147895/466039):

```
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode=3.20180312.0~ubuntu18.04.1
```

Then freeze the package to avoid accidental upgrade:

```
sudo su 
echo "intel-microcode" hold | dpkg --set-selections
```

Maybe some similar solution can fix the issue on Ubuntu 16 I just didn't find the right package version to downgrade to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete video about this problem, actually for an Asus Zenbook: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbxrSaclKRc

Summary of the fix:

add the boot parameter: dis_ucode_ldr to /etc/default/grub
then: update-grub

More info here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1829620